# how can i hook multiple post type in single

Tags: custom-post-types

Just have experienced to create single/multiple custom post type in any wordpress theme but i am looking for to gather/bind or it can say hook all custom post type in single post type.

Suppose, i have few post types like  'products' ,  'news', 'movies', 'sports'.. so on and all these post types i want keep in single post type named 'all-post-types'. So when i click the 'all-post-type' it will show all these post types as submenu or as child something like appearance/settings menu in admin panel.

Any idea please ??

Answer (score 0):

Better if you stay use different post types but group its in one admin menu (look to http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/customizing-your-wordpress-admin/ and http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)